# Access denied in AWS S3 for HTTP POST form

Tags: html, http, post, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

### What would cause **Access Denied** when posting to a folder in a bucket of AWS S3?

```
<html>
<form 
        action="https://<BUCKETNAME>.s3.amazonaws.com"
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input
        type="hidden"  name="key"
        value="<BASEFOLDER>/testfile.txt" /> <input type="hidden"
        name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<KEY>" /> <input
        type="hidden"  name="policy" value="<ENCODEDPOLICY>" /> <input
        type="hidden"  name="signature" value="<ENCODEDSIGN>" /> <input
        type="hidden"  name="acl"
        value="public-read" />

        <input type="hidden"  name="Content-Type" value="text/plain" /> 

        <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="https://www.google.co.uk/" /> 
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Send to Amazon" />
                <input type="file" size="50" name="file" />
</form>
</html>
```

Policy generating class (please note that single apostrophe is the text delimiter in Salesforce).

```
public class Aws2 {

    datetime expire = system.now().addDays(1);
    String formattedexpire = expire.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd')+'T'+
        expire.formatGmt('HH:mm:ss')+'.'+expire.formatGMT('SSS')+'Z';           

    string policy { get {return 
        '{ "expiration": "'+formattedexpire+'","conditions": [ {"bucket": "<BUCKETNAME>" } ,{ "acl": "public-read" },'+
        '{"content-type":"text/plain"},'+
        '{"success_action_redirect": "https://www.google.co.uk/"},' +
        '["starts-with", "$key", ""] ]}';   } } 

    public String getPolicy() {
        system.debug('Policy = ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy)));
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy));
    }

    public String getSignedPolicy() {
        system.debug('Signed policy = ' + make_sig(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy))));
        return make_sig(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy)));        
    }

    //method that will sign
    private String make_sig(string canonicalBuffer) {        
        String macUrl ;
        String signingKey = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('<SECRETKEY>'));
        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMacSHA1', blob.valueof(canonicalBuffer),blob.valueof('<SECRETKEY>')); 
        macUrl = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);                
        return macUrl;
    }
}
```

.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>3567EC72BE0423C4</RequestId>
<HostId>
4oOTHxcrC9c6kXsj6jicWqItfMHQB5Lqx2vXzpMZQlnoEN0bfyuGp/SQyHNIRoxR
</HostId>
</Error>
```

### Just for the sake of completeness:

I'd say that the encoded policy and signature are correct. If I tamper with either of them, I get a new error message as I would expect.

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>Blah blah</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>Blah blah
</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>Blah blah</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>Blah blah
</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>Blah blah</RequestId>
<HostId>Blah blah
</HostId>
</Error>
```

So what would cause Access Denied when posting to a folder in a bucket of AWS S3?

Comment: Technically, by tweaking the data (an excellent demonstration of good troubleshooting) you have only proven that the secret matches the access key, and that  signature matches the policy; you haven't proven that the policy matches the actual form post.  Show the policy?  If you redact it, do so with careful attention to modify the form exactly the same way, byte-for-byte.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I have now redacted the policy in the question with careful attention.

Comment: Does the user that "owns" the Access Key have permissions to upload to the bucket? Also, why do you include the "starts-with" check in the policy if you are not interested in the value? Or perhaps use `["starts-with", "$key", "<BASEFOLDER>/"]`

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. It's a placeholder for future so I have kept it blank for now. It works for my personal S3 but not on the vendor's S3. I have tried including the base folder in the policy, but it's the same error.

Comment: Make sure that the Access Key belongs to a User that has permissions to access the bucket. To test, try using the Access Key & Secret Key with the CLI to copy a file to the bucket (`aws s3 cp file.txt s3://bucketname/folder/file.txt`). If that works, then at least you know the User permissions are correct.

Comment: I am having a similar issue and the error message is `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$x-amz-credential", "AKIAJEU76OGABPGMWWCA/20170624/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request"]`. Not sure what to do. Plz help.

Comment: I've had the same error, in my case a workaround was to remove ACL (completely) both from the form and policy. I'm working on a clean solution now.